# Вывод десятичного числа

Tags: linux, ассемблер, nasm

*На случай, если пригодится: код пишется на Linux и в NASM-е*.

**Кратко**: В регистре предположительно должны храниться целые числа, которые предварительно вводятся с клавиатуры. Как выводить эти числа, если между выводом и вводом над ними будут произведены математические операции?

**Не кратко**: Суть задачи - простейший калькулятор (операции сложения и вычитания) для чисел, введённых с клавиатуры. Опыт написания программ на NASM-е минимальный, однако уже имею какой-то набор заранее написанных подпрограмм: *sread* и *swrite*.

**swrite**

```
;Функция для вывода строки, адрес на которой хранится в eax, на экран
swrite: ;Выводим строку на экран
push edx; значения регистров сохраняются в стек
push ecx
push ebx
push eax
call _strlen; вызов подпрограммы для вычисления длины строки

mov edx, eax; сохраняем вычисленную длину строки в edx
pop eax; восстанавливаем из стека указатель на строку

; инициализация остальных регистров для системного вызова SYS_WRITE
mov ecx, eax
mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1
int 80h; выполняем системный вызов

; восстанавливаем значения остальных регистров
pop ebx
pop ecx
pop edx
ret
```

**sread**

```
;Функция для ввода строки с клавиатуры в eax-адрес длины ebx
sread:
push edx ;Сохраняем исходные значения edx и ebx
push ebx

mov ecx, eax ;Перемещаем исходные данные 
mov edx, ebx

mov eax, 3 ;Подготавливаемся к считыванию
mov ebx, 0

int 80h ;Системный вызов считывания

pop edx ;Возвращаем исходные значения edx и ebx
pop ebx
ret
```

Комментарии написаны мною для малейшего понимания, что здесь происходит, так что не обращайте на них внимания.
В основной программе я пытаюсь с помощью *sread* считать в переменную input1 какое-то число, проделать тоже самое с переменной input2 и вывести их на экран:

```
section .bss
input1 resb 256
input2 resb 256

…

;Суммирование чисел
_summ:
;Вводим числа

mov eax, input1
mov ebx, 256
call sread

mov eax, input2
mov ebx, 256
call sread

mov eax, input1
adc eax,input2
daa ;Коррекция чисел BCD формата

call swrite
```

Программа вылетает, выдавая "*Ошибка сегментирования (сделан дамп памяти)
*". Нашёл пару примеров с вводом чисел через вызов "**21h**", однако там код писался для MS-DOS, и у меня при попытке сделать то же самое программа вновь вылетает.

Просьба помочь разобраться, что я делаю не так при сложении чисел.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы попробуете использовать отладчик, например [gdb](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Debugger) или [SASM (SimpleASM)](https://dman95.github.io/SASM/), то таких вопросов у вас больше не возникнет. Было дело с MS-DOS, когда писали калькуляторы, разные писали и бинарный, и восьмеричный, и тд. Но тогда это решалось прерываниями 01-02. И да, ошибок по коду и сегментам на момент написания всегда было много поэтому всегда выручал  отладчик.

Comment: Никто не может гарантировать, что завтра автор репозитория завтра не удалит его, и ваш ответ сведется к "используйте отладчик". Поэтому если хотите привести пример кода - нужно приводить его прямо в ответе (с ссылкой на источник, если код не ваш).

Comment: Не вижу смысла искать segmentation fault в неполном коде, к тому же код не на столько большой, чтобы не пройтись по нему отладчиком и посмотреть его состояние во время работы. Поэтому, ответ в любом случае сводится к "используйте отладчик".

Comment: Добавит ли ясности то, что при отладке происходит Segmentation fault in _strlen.nextchar() после успешного ввода чисел с клавиатуры?
(Возникает проблема отслеживания того, что хранится в переменных input1 и input2. Команда info variables отображает названия переменных, их адреса, но не значения, хранимые в них.)

Comment: А в чем у вас возникает трудность в отладчике посмотреть что по данным адресам храниться? Это во первых, во вторых код _strlen у вас идет отдельно или из библиотеки вызывается?

Comment: Ага-м, нашёл (предположительно) необходимую команду для просмотра значения того, что хранится под данным адресом. Попробую-с.
А _strlen лежит в том же файле, где и основной код.

Comment: Увы, то, что возвращает _info symbol_ , мне не очень помогло. Возможно, я не [там](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_node/gdb_109.html) ищу нужную мне команду?

Comment: Если  ошибка сегментации возникает в коде _strlen, попробуйте отлаживать ее или заменить на другую, в интернете много вариантов функции _strlen для nasm. Также используй точки останова и stepi или nexti для пошаговой отладки.